# Mounting a small mirror on frosted glass?

Tags: mounting, mirror

I have a small IKEA mirror with a battery powered lamp I'd like to mount above my washbasin. My washbasin is in front of a textured glass window facing the street. I tried the suction cup and sticky pads that came with the mirror, but the suction cup won't suck and the sticky pads last 1-2 minutes before it drops.

What's the best way to solve this? Would taping/painting over the glass work? superglue? a bigger suction cup?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a few dabs of silicone bathroom sealer at the corners and hold it in place until it sets.

It wouldn’t take much to hold and if you want to remove it later dental floss slid behind acts like a chainsaw on the silicone. I glue plastic name plates to equipment at work, sometimes the instructions change so a new plate is needed, a minute and a couple feet of dental floss removes the old nameplate, your mirror would work the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a product made by 3M called Outdoor Mounting Tape, sometimes called Outdoor Permanent Mounting Tape. It's a slightly-foamy strip with adhesive on both sides and a tremendous grip and durability.

[image: permanent mounting tape]

It's available via Amazon, as well as many local outlets. My local grocery chain carries it in the utility items aisle.

I've mounted items to my windshield, which tolerates the summer heat well. I've mounted a sports team to a motor vehicle, which endured countless mechanized vehicle washes.

The foaminess allows for irregularities in the surface, such as the textured glass you reference.

The "permanent" aspect is not exactly thus. One can remove it with a razor, sharp knife or some have used dental floss!